# Android App isn't installed in emulator

Tags: android, fragment, android-manifest, android-fragmentactivity

I've been searching solution for this issue, but seem there's no correct answer in my case. 
I have an app and all classes I used Activity to navigate among screens, and the first screen as launcher is WelcomeActivity. 
Now I have to change the app to use tab, and my launcher activity is now TutorialFragmentActivity and the WelcomeActivity I converted to Fragment to use as a tab in my application, and same for other Activity classes. I only have Tutorial & Main (Main contains tabhost) class are FragmentActivity, the other classes I converted to Fragment. 
I'm not sure if that caused the "App isn't installed" issue, I did read one post and they said that changing launcher class name would cause this, and I tried to rename my TutorialFragmentActivity to WelcomeActivity but the problem still exist. 
Would you please help me out with this problem? 
I still can run the app from Emulator, I just got problem when I clicked on the app icon.

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, when I changed all my classes to Fragment, and add another TabActivity class, I forgot to add that class to Manifest